# Focus on form field after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'd like to display at short d3 animation and upon completion, have a form field become automatically selected/focused to take user input.

It seems like it is best accomplished through chaining functions. I tried to use the javascript function focus() that selects the form field ("signup","inputname") on load, but this isn't working.

How do I select a form field automatically after animation completion?

d3.js:

```
<script>
selectReady = d3.selectAll("#ready")
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("color", "red");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("color", "black");})           
    .on("mousedown", animateDisplay); //starts animation with a mousepress

function animateDisplay(){
    d3.selectAll("#Display")
        .transition()
        .delay(200)            
        .duration(1000)             
        .style("color","white") // changes Display to white
        .each("end",selectForm);
};

function selectForm(){
    d3.select("#inputname")
        .focus(); // remove() works here
};  

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="ready">Click when ready<p></th>
<p id='Display'>A</p>
<p id='Display'>B</p>
<p id='Display'>C</p>

<form name="signup" id="signup" method="post" action="#">   
    <table> 
        <tr>        
        <td colspan="2" class="labelcell"><label for="name">Name</label></td>   
        <td colspan="2" class="fieldcell">      
            <input type="text" name="inputname" id="inputname" tabindex="1" />  
        </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use on keydown? why not just `.each("end",function () { if (this is last frame) document.response.inputname.focus()});`

Comment: That's fine -- however, this doesn't work either. I'm wondering if it's a problem with focus()

Comment: I have added d3 to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JfvbD/) can you add the code and html to show the example?

Comment: Edited the question for easier fiddling (included all code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was clear [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mplungjan/JfvbD/)

```
d3.select("#inputname").focus is not a function
http://fiddle.jshell.net/mplungjan/JfvbD/show/
Line 41
```

Here you go

I changed to this

```
<p id='DisplayA' class="disp">A</p>
<p id='DisplayB' class="disp">B</p>
<p id='DisplayC' class="disp">C</p>
```

so I could use this:

```
d3.selectAll(".disp")
```

and have the code

```
function selectForm(){
  if (this.id!="DisplayC") return;
  document.getElementById('inputname').focus();  
};
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! The function `document.getElementById('inputname').focus()` was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 13):

Use [selection.node](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-node) to access the underlying DOM element, and then [element.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus):

```
d3.select("#inputname").node().focus()
```