# Why does D3's focus on an input work only the first time?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, focus, forms

It's possible to [focus on an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824963/704972) using D3, without even the need [to go through `setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096938/704972) (I don't know why, but I'm not complaining).

But this only works the first time. After the second press on `Set` (i.e.: `Set`, `Reset`, `Set`), the input field does not receive focus. Why?

Setting a callback to focus [after the transition is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10692220/704972) gives me an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <style>
        div { width: 300px; }
        div#outerdiv  { height: 500px; background-color: #ccc; }
        div#topdiv    { height: 400px; background-color: #dff; }
        div#bottomdiv { height: 0px;   background-color: #ffd; display: 'none' }
        input:focus { background-color: pink; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerdiv">
        <div id="topdiv">
            <button onclick=open_form();>Set</button>
            <button onclick=close_form();>Reset</button>
        </div>

        <div id="bottomdiv">
            <form action="javascript:close_form()">
                Name:
                <input type="text" id="myTextField" name="name">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function open_form() {
            d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '100px');
            d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '300px').style('display', 'inline-block');

            d3.select("#myTextField").node().focus();
        } 
        function close_form() {
            d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '390px');
            d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
              .style('height', '10px').style('display', 'none');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you hit the *Reset* button, i.e. when `close_form()` is called, your `#bottomdiv` is transitioned to `display: none`:

```
d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
    .style('height', '10px').style('display', 'none');
```

This has some side effects, though. Looking at the HTML5 spec on [focus management](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus-management) shows, that an element, which is not being rendered, is also not focusable:

> #### 7.4.2 Focus management
>
> An element is focusable if all of the following conditions are met:
>
> - *[…]*
> - The element is either [being rendered](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#being-rendered) or *[…]*.

Hence, the next time you hit *Set* whereby invoking `open_form()` the input is not focusable because the transition to `inline-block` has not come to an end yet. The easiest way around this is to [listen](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on) for the transition's `end` event which is fired once the transition ends.

```
   d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
       .style('height', '300px').style('display', 'inline-block')
       .on("end", () => d3.select("#myTextField").node().focus());
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
function open_form() {
    d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
      .style('height', '100px');
    d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
      .style('height', '300px').style('display', 'inline-block')
      .on("end", () => d3.select("#myTextField").node().focus());

} 
function close_form() {
    d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
      .style('height', '390px');
    d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
      .style('height', '10px').style('display', 'none');
}
```

```css
div { width: 300px; }
div#outerdiv  { height: 500px; background-color: #ccc; }
div#topdiv    { height: 400px; background-color: #dff; }
div#bottomdiv { height: 0px;   background-color: #ffd; display: 'none' }
input:focus { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="outerdiv">
        <div id="topdiv">
            <button onclick=open_form();>Set</button>
            <button onclick=close_form();>Reset</button>
        </div>

        <div id="bottomdiv">
            <form action="javascript:close_form()">
                Name:
                <input type="text" id="myTextField" name="name">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Homework to self: figure out the difference between .on('end', ..) and .each('end', ..) as listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692100/invoke-a-callback-at-the-end-of-a-transition/10692220#10692220

Comment: @Sebastian Well, [`transition.each("end")`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#each) was the way of registering handler functions in v3. As of v4 this was renamed to [`transition.on("end")`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_on).

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't able to find #myTextField because it was mid-transition. You can fix this by removing the transition for display: inline-block, as seen below.

```
function open_form() {
    d3.select('#topdiv').transition().duration(500)
      .style('height', '100px');
    d3.select('#bottomdiv').style('display', 'inline-block');
    d3.select('#bottomdiv').transition().duration(500)
      .style('height', '300px');
    d3.select("#myTextField").node().focus();
}
```